# Alembic autogenerate from current database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a database with a few  tables in schema_a and views of these tables in schema_b, and want to use `alembic revision --autogenerate` to run have alembic detect the views i've created.

When I run `alembic revision --autogenerate` either using metadata with models.py generated from `sqlacodegen` my views are represented as tables in the resultant code. Ideally I would like to create a migration that represents the *current state* of the database, as it was initialized using handmade SQL for all the views and tables. When I look into the autogenerated migrations, i see discrepancies between schemas and views/tables as mentioned. Is there anyway to get a `MetaData()` object for a running PSQL database instead of relying on `models.py` metadata object (which doesnt seem to be correct)?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to, in my `env.py` file create a metadata from the running database configuration:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    target_metadata = MetaData()
    #Connect to running db:
    engine = create_engine(url)
    target_metadata.reflect(bind=engine, views=True, schema="myschema")
    with engine.connect() as connection:
          # set up context and run migrations
```

Using `alembic_utils`, I am able to detect the views correctly.